# PHP Mailer class in Elastic Beanstalk not recognised

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

As I understand it with an Elastic Beanstalk if you include a `composer.json` file in root directory and DO NOT include a vendor file than composer will automatically handle the library from the JSON instructions.

The `composer.json` file is as per the current 51 line json file on PHPMailer Github and it sits in my EB root folder with `/public` and `.ebextensions`

Then I have this PHP script (`public/phphead.php`), copied from AWS docs

```
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace

// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// If necessary, modify the path in the require statement below to refer to the
// location of your Composer autoload.php file.
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

// requiring /vendor/autoload.php would throw a fatal error and so I presume this is where composer creates the vendor dir. no more fatal errors have been thrown and I have been looking to confirm this is the right location but I have only the lack of errors to make me think composer is found and working...
// ....
$mail = new PHPMailer(); //LINE 64 as per error log
```

Error log outputs from the EB:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in
>   /var/app/current/public/phpHead.php:64\nStack trace:\n#0
>   /var/app/current/public/index.php(3): include()\n#1 {main}\n thrown in
>   /var/app/current/public/phpHead.php on line 64

The `composer.json` I'm using (same as PHPMailer's `composer.json` file, as taken from GitHub):

> ```
> {
>     "name": "phpmailer/phpmailer",
>     "type": "library",
>     "description": "PHPMailer is a full-featured email creation and transfer class for PHP",
>     "authors": [
>         {
>             "name": "Marcus Bointon",
>             "email": "phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "Jim Jagielski",
>             "email": "jimjag@gmail.com"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "Andy Prevost",
>             "email": "codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "Brent R. Matzelle"
>         }
>     ],
>     "require": {
>         "php": ">=5.5.0",
>         "ext-ctype": "*",
>         "ext-filter": "*"
>     },
>     "require-dev": {
>         "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.2",
>         "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8 || ^5.7",
>         "doctrine/annotations": "^1.2"
>     },
>     "suggest": {
>         "psr/log": "For optional PSR-3 debug logging",
>         "league/oauth2-google": "Needed for Google XOAUTH2 authentication",
>         "hayageek/oauth2-yahoo": "Needed for Yahoo XOAUTH2 authentication",
>         "stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft": "Needed for Microsoft XOAUTH2 authentication",
>         "ext-mbstring": "Needed to send email in multibyte encoding charset",
>         "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "To support UTF-8 if the Mbstring PHP extension is not enabled (^1.2)"
>     },
>     "autoload": {
>         "psr-4": {
>             "PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\": "src/"
>         }
>     },
>     "autoload-dev": {
>         "psr-4": {
>             "PHPMailer\\Test\\": "test/"
>         }
>     },
>     "license": "LGPL-2.1-only"
> }
> ```

Comment: This looks like what happens when you have not run `composer install`. I don't know how EB is supposed to deal with this, but the problem is definitely in there and not in your code.

Comment: try like this Use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer instead of PHPMailer

Comment: @Synchro - thanks, that's my feeling... I am trying to do this without the CLI, is there a way to check composer is installed/installing?

Comment: @Dlk isn't that what I have? if you mean new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(); then i have tried that (without 'use')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used EB, but based on your assumption that it will run `composer install` when needed, you need to include a valid `composer.json`.

You are including the **package's** composer.json. So you are installing the PHPMailer's dependencies, but not PHPMailer itself.

You need to create your own `composer.json` file for your project/application, where you declare PHPMailer a dependency for your app.

E.g.:

```
{
  "name": "your/app",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "",
  "license": "CC-0",
  "require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.1"
    }
}
```

In any case, you should try your code (including original dependencies install) **offline**, before you upload it to EB.

If you tried to run `composer install` and running your project off-line, you would have hit the same problem. Get your basic project running **before** deployment.

Comment: Thanks @yivi - much appreciated. You are right about running local obviously but I am just playing around with EB, precisely to see what can be set up without CLI - thanks again